# Batch search multiple strings simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, findstr

I have this large database of equipment:

```
Equipment500
Equipment501
..........
Equipment998
Equipment999
```

As well  as an even larger database with details about equipment:

```
Equipment1:details....
Equipment2:details....
..................
Equipment9998:details....
Equipment9999:details....
```

What i need, is to select only the details for equipment i need:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%cd%\equipment.db) do (
findstr /i /c:"%%a" details.db > Output\%%a
)
```

The output will be, of course, a folder with files:

```
In Equipment500 it will be Equipment500:details....
In Equipment501 it will be Equipment501:details....
..................
In Equipment998 it will be Equipment998:details....
In Equipment999 it will be Equipment999:details....
```

The problem is that it takes a lot of time. 

**I need this multithreaded so that it runs more instances of findstr (preferably all 500) at the sametime to do processing instantly.**

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Split the entry into multiple subsets if you want to work in parallel. This is the easiest way.

Comment: I didn't  test, if there is a limit, but `findstr /G` sounds like a good solution. See `findstr /?` for explanation

Comment: @Marichyasana I removed it from the code. It was extracted from another script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo building input files (this needs some time):
del *.db
for /l %%i in (500,1,999) do @echo Equipment%%i>>equipment.db
for /l %%i in (1,1,9999) do @echo Equipment%%i:Detailswhatever>>details.db

echo %time% start adapting
REM adapt equipment.db:
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (equipment.db) do echo %%i:)>equip.db

REM find all strings:
echo %time% start searching
findstr /g:equip.db details.db >output.txt
echo %time% done
```

NOTE: "Equipment.db" has to be adapted, because searching for "Equipment2" would also find "Equipment20", Equipment21"... "Equipment200" ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed meanwhile to make findstr /g work. I didn't realize your "NOTE". In my particular case the equipment names are uniques ( always have 4 numbers ), so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: There is however a problem. I need each equipment details in its own file for later purpose.

Comment: Anyway since this is done almost instantly, i am sure the code `for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%cd%\equip.db) do (
findstr /i /c:"%%a" output.txt > Output\%%a
)` will also execute almost instantly. I am checking it right now

Comment: I tested this method. I see a slightly improve in execution time (~2sec) . Still the second part takes a lot of time to create a file for each. I would need to create files only for equipment needed. The problem is that there are more lines of details for each. like this `Equipment500:detail1 \n Equipment500:detail2 etc`

Comment: what about combining Magoos answer with my "output.txt" instead of "details.db"?

Comment: My luck is that i only need a certain line containing "extern" string. So i did `findstr /i "extern" output.txt > %cd%\out.txt` . This is executed in an incredible 0.1 sec :) From here i will export each line in a file containing the first string with filename equal to what it is until delimiter :

Comment: You are right. Combing them results in exactly what i need. With an execution time of about 0.2 sec

Answer (score 1):

Since you only provide vague information about your file structure, I'd suggest

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in (details.db) do >>%%a.dat echo %%b
```

which assumes each entry in `details.db` is of the form

```
equipment1234:details
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mixing your code with Stephan's, results in exactly what i need